# What are the downsides of <input type="radio">-based tabs and carousels?

Tags: input, tabs, radio-buttons

I have seen a lot of examples of usage of `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">` along with some css like

```
input:checked + div.tab-content {display:block;}
div.tab-content {display:none;}
```

to implement js-free tabs, dropdowns etc.

This is clearly a hack, but what are the exact UX downsides (e.g. for accessibility) of this approach? Am I better off with some bootstrap-based or `:target`-based tabs?

To explain better here's couple implementations:

- top google result for ["css only tabs"](https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/812ehkyf/)
- [another one](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/tabbed-panels/)
- [here's another](https://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/bdGdOb), navigable by arrows (@Alvaro so keyboard navigation is not an issue, only what keys are expected), I like it the most so far.

Comment: Perfectly valid question, but it may be better suited for stack overflow.

Comment: @WilliamAnderson I think it is much better off here, because what I want to know is what does it change in terms of UX, not implementation.

Comment: I suggest you to provide a picture with your question- for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @YuvalPruss I linked a couple of examples

Comment: @WilliamAnderson I think that whether the tabs are JavaScript or a CSS trick with radios makes no difference to the user experience, simply because the user doesn't know about or perceive any difference in the implementations. Unless your case is somehow different? 

I can think of one exception: using CSS for tabs means you don't have to use JavaScript, which means you may not need to download any libraries (such as jQuery). In that case you'd see a speed boost which would have a minor positive effect on the overall experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you take [this W3 schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tab_header) which uses both CSS and JavaScript you can see how the elements used for the tabs are buttons rather than inputs.

The difference here is that, when using the Keyboard Tab button, buttons can be focused one by one while radio inputs are [focused as a group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322755/1176359) and then you need to use arrow up/down keys to navigate through them.

In the example you post the actual input is hidden (`display:none`) and the label is what the user can click (which automatically selects the input). As far as I could test the labels are not able to receive focus, so it is not possible to navigate through them with the keyboard.

Comment: I would also add the fact that to scroll with up/down arrows user has to unfocus the input group.